# Leading Zero Date Format C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this function...

```
private string dateConvert(string datDate)
{
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultEnGb = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultEnUs = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

        DateTime dtGb = Convert.ToDateTime(datDate, cultEnGb.DateTimeFormat);
        datDate = dtGb.ToString(cultEnUs.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);

        return datDate;
}
```

But I want it with the leading zero still on lower digits (1-9) so the date is 11-09-2009 (mm-dd-yyyy)...

Now If I wasn't converting it id use string.Format("{0:d}", dateVar) how do I do this in the conversion?

******* Solution *******
Used a slightly modified version of the answer below (i.e. one that would render).

```
Convert.ToDateTime(datDate).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

Comment: To ask the silly question, is there a reason that you're not parsing this and then keeping it as a date value until you need to present it back to the user?

Comment: Its to produce a deeplink, meeting the requirements of the 3rd party application we use.
This is part of a larger script to make it easier on partners to link in. English Company, Indian Developers, US Date Format. Go Figure.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
return dateTimeValue.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

Comment: Agreed - from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(VS.85).aspx the ShortDatePattern of EN-US is "M/d/yyyy", which will trim leading zeros and use "/" as the seperator not "-".

Comment: @Zhaph: the date is reparsed and passed in the URL so - seperation is necessary.

Comment: This didn't work for my purposes (in whole) but modifying it to...
Convert.ToDateTime(datDate).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
worked a treat. Thanks

Comment: Hard-coding a date time format is bad for globalization. There has got to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you use the `string.Format` after you've done the conversion?

ie `return string.Format("{0:d}", datDate);`

Comment: Thats what I Guessed but entering 20-03-2009 produced 3-20-2009

Comment: Yeah, dunno what I was thinking, Mehrdad's answer is the one that should work

Comment: Why do you keep the answer?

Comment: The `d` format output depends on the CultureInfo. So for en-US is will give 3/20/2009, for invariant it will give 03/20/2009, for german it will give 20.3.2009 etc.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the latest C# shorthand (format specifier) for usability and readability's sake:

```
return dateTimeValue:MM-dd-yyyy;
```

Clean and concise.