# How do I detect the current culture of the executing thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0, culture

I have a nice function setup for formatting dates as per 
[Leading Zero Date Format C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461098/leading-zero-date-format-c-asp-net)

But it turns out in our farm we have some blades running on a UK locale and some on a US locale so depending on which it crashes.

So what I'm after is how do I test the current server locale?

Something like...

```
if(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == "GB"){
...

}
else
{

..otherstatement
}
```

Ta

Comment: I would suggest getting rid of any code that is so fragile that it breaks if you change locals ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass in the desired culture to all of your formatting functions (InvariantCulture, usually).

Alternatively, you can *set* the culture on the page [like so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx). That code could also go in the Application BeginRequest override in your asax.cs file in order to affect all pages.

Comment: Set the page culture; should of remembered this considering I had to do it to an entire classic ASP app a month ago.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
Date now = DateTime.Now;
CultureInfo ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("d", ci));
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually we [go with UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC) instead of locale specific code.

Comment: That would be my personal preference but basically I'm converting the date from UK to US to meet a 3rd party api requirement

Answer (score 1):

Testing for CurrentCulture is the only way to achieve what you ask for, as far as I know. However, I would strongly suggest to keep dates as DateTime until they are to be presented in the user interface, and not have if-statements in server functionality that is relying on date formats.

I usually try to apply date formatting as close to the user as possible.