# how to convert number to digit zeros in c #?

Tags: c#

I want to convert numbers to zeros like

```
int instore = docvotdig;
int invot = docstoredig;
int diffrent = docvotdig - docstoredig;
int instore = docvotdig;
```

I want to convert the result to 00000 like if the result 2 i want it '00', if 3 '000' like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Leading Zero Date Format C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461098/leading-zero-date-format-c-sharp)

Comment: @Samuel I disagree with that duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

```
int num = 5;
var zeros = new string('0', num);
```

Will yield:

```
00000
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int zeroCount = 5;
            char charToPrint = '0';
            Console.Write(new string(charToPrint, zeroCount));
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```