# Short-date and short-time pattern in .NET with leading zeroes

Tags: .net, date, datetime

I would like to display short date and short time in fixed width columns, like the output of the DIR command. I would like to keep this fixed width format as close to the local date/time convention as possible. If local format is already fixed width, use it. Otherwise, use the nearest fixed-width thing.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461098/leading-zero-date-format-c-sharp) has been asked before, but the answer "use dateTimeValue.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")" is not very useful, because it kills localization.

Some local date-time formats are already fixed width. E.g. for Germany (de-DE), short date format string is "dd.MM.yyyy", which yields 10 characters for any date.

On the other hand, American ("en-US") format is "M/d/yyyy". This produces strings of variable width:

```
3/1/2011 - 8 characters
3/12/2011 - 9 characters
12/31/2011 - 10 characters.
```

Similar problem exists for the time portion: "1:34 PM" has less characters than "12:30 AM".

Yet, the "dir" command, even on American windows shows the dates and times neatly aligned, with leading zeroes.

```
08/13/2011  09:48 PM            14,336 holidays.xls
08/14/2011  12:47 PM            36,352 holidays2.xls
```

Perhaps a regular expressions that extracts free-standing h,H,d,M and replaces them with hh,HH,dd, and MM respectively would help, but I am hoping someone has already done (and tested!) that and I can borrow from the common wisdom.

Comment: Maybe you could search the output of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns('d')` and somehow pich a string that contains `MM` and `dd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only occurrences of single digits on Gregorian dates and times are those you want to pad, so a regex replace would definitely be a correct and practical solution:

```
var padded = Regex.Replace(dateOrTimeString, @"(?<=^|\D)(\d)(?=\D|$)", "0$1");
```

This matches all digits that are neither preceded nor followed by another digit and prepends a zero. Works for dates, times, and combined date/times too.

Comment: Short and elegant solution. Thank you! I did not even know .NET regexes had such thing as "zero width positive lookbehind" :) Looks like it's been there since version 1.1.